# clicking a button then will store the username to another database table

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to create a button that when an user click on it, it will automatic retrieve the username from the firebase database. Then, it will store into another database.it's like someone is booking an item. Lastly it will show on the page the username that already book the service.

This is the blogsingleactivity java file.

```
public class BlogSingleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mSubmitBook;;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseBookUser;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


List<Blog> Info;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blog_single);
    firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mSubmitBook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitBook);
    mDatabaseBookUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    Info = new ArrayList<>();

    mSubmitBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(view== mSubmitBook){
            addName();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This page is the register java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button buttonRegister;
private EditText mMatricField;
private EditText mNameField;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private TextView textViewSignin;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
        //profile activity here
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class));
    }
    mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);

    buttonRegister=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

    mMatricField= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.matricField);
    mNameField=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameField);
    editTextEmail=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

    textViewSignin=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignin);

    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    textViewSignin.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void registerUser(){
    final String matric=mMatricField.getText().toString().trim();
    final String name= mNameField.getText().toString().trim();
    String email=editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(matric)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter matric number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //stopping the function execution further
        return;

    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //stopping the function execution further
        return;

    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //email is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //stopping the function execution further
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //stopping the function execution further
        return;

    }
    //if validation are ok
    //we will first show a progressbar

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User...");
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        String user_id=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user_db= mDatabase.child(user_id);
                        current_user_db.child("name").setValue(name);
                        current_user_db.child("matric").setValue(matric);
                        current_user_db.child("image").setValue("default");
                        //user is successfully registered and logged in
                        //we will start the profile activity here
                        //display a toast only
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Could not register... Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view== buttonRegister){
        registerUser();
    }
    if(view== textViewSignin){
        //will open login activity here
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to use `FirebaseOptions.Builder`, where you keep two different references for the two "Firebase Projects".

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/ for details.